# In what cases can we or had we better omit "please" when you use an imperative sentence to a stranger?

Tags: word-usage

I always find it difficult to use the word "please".
When you use an imperative sentence politely to a stranger, it is generally safe to use "please".
For example, "Please don't smoke here."
Of course, when you demand a stranger to do something, you usually don't use it. For example, "Get out!"

However, it seems to me there are cases in which you can or better omit "please" even if you mean to say it politely.
For example, when you say "Feel free to do something".
Am I right?
If yes, what cases are they? Are there some general rules with which we can decide whether to use "please" or not?
I think this is an interesting problem of the English language. 
Do you have any book recommendation on this subject?

**Edit**

Since some people seem to misunderstand my question, I will add some other examples.

Steve Jobs said in his speech at Stanford university, "Stay Hungry. Stay Foolish."
It seems to me "Please stay hungry and foolish" is acceptable but awkward.

"Have a nice weekend."

"Watch out!"

"Sleep tight."

"Take care."

**Edit**

I searched COCA(Corpus of Contemporary American English):

Please feel free to: 50

Feel free to: 967

Comment: For example, in a store you might hear, "Feel free to look around.". This does not need *please* because it is not asking anything. It is just giving permission.

Comment: It may be unnecessary to say "please" when you are making demands  while pointing a gun at the other person's head. But it still doesn't hurt.

Comment: I'm sorry, but _"Please stay hungry and foolish"_ isn't a request. It's something Jobs observed and that's him telling what he observed. You should edit out that part from the original question.

Comment: @VarunKN He said that to the audience:
*Beneath it were the words: "Stay Hungry. Stay Foolish." It was their farewell message
as they signed off. Stay Hungry. Stay Foolish. And I have always wished that for myself.
And now, as you graduate to begin anew, I wish that for you.
Stay Hungry. Stay Foolish.
Thank you all very much.*

Comment: Those last four examples – _Have a nice weekend; take care;_ etc. – are good examples where no "please" is necessary. When you're wishing someone well with standard verbiage, there's no need to insert a _please_. In fact, doing so _every time_ might come across as a bit bizarre.

Comment: In Japanese ***kudasai*** is similar to **please**, but Japanese also has other forms: **formal** / **polite** i.e. the difference between ***mina-san*** and ***mina-sama***, ***onegaishimasu*** (I beg of you) and the use of ***kamaimasen ka*** (if you don't mind) when asking permission.  These all get wrapped up into **please** (English) in various forms.

Comment: In his [2005 Stanford Commencement speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UF8uR6Z6KLc), Steve Jobs cites the last issue of the Whole Earth Catalog saying: **Stay Hungry**, **Stay Foolish**. It is an imperative (command) rather than a request.  You can think of it as the motto for WEC which captured the *zeitgeist* of the 70's.

Comment: @J.R. "*When you're wishing someone well with standard verbiage, there's no need to insert a please.*" What about "Watch out"? This is not a wish.

Comment: There are three close votes. Please tell me the reason why you voted to close the question before it it actually closed.

Comment: @MakotoKato - That's not "wishing someone well," that's warning them that there's about to be beaned in the head (or run over by a car, etc.) When I said: _wishing someone well with standard verbiage,_ I was referring to greetings like, "Have a nice day!" or "Good morning!" or "Nice to see you!" Generally speaking, we don't add a _please_ to such comments.

Comment: @J.R. I knew "Watch out" is not "wishing someone well". The point of my question is that: are there general rules about when we can or better omit "please"? If yes, what are they(the rules)? Please keep in mind that it is not always easy to decide whether to use "please" or not for non-native English speakers.

Comment: @MakotoKato - I don't know if it can be summarized so briefly. "Watch out, please" wouldn't usually make sense, but if we were walking through a construction site, and I almost touched a live electrical wire, I suppose you could say, "Watch out, please; I don't want you to get electrocuted."  It's tricky.

Comment: @J.R. Maybe it's tricky. So are the uses(or non-uses) of articles. But there are the grammar rules  for them.

Comment: Makoto I suggest you just keep listening to native speakers, or watching English-language movies. You will actually remember better if you hear a usage in context than just read a list. English speakers don't have a list of when to use *please* and when not to use it: we just use it. It is really context specific. Frankly, I close-voted this question because it is too broad and also opinion-based.

Comment: @GoDucks The use of articles is a big subject of English grammar.
There are books which are entirely devoted to the subject.
When someone asks for book recommendations on the subject, you should not close their question.
I think the same can be said to my question.

Comment: It was me who accidentally upvoted GoDucks' comment avove. I intended to down vote it. Unfortunately you cannot reset your vote for a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you acknowledge, "please" is a polite filler word.

So when is it best NOT to say "please"?

(a) If you are trying to be abrupt or rude. "Get out before I throw you out!" is more effective than "Would you please make your way to the exit".

(b) If you are trying to express urgency. Like if you know the stove is hot and see someone about to touch it, it makes sense to shout, "Don't touch the stove!" If you said, "Please don't touch the stove", it makes it sound like a mild request. The person might casually touch it thinking they're about to ask, "Oh, why not?" Arguably, in an emergency where a fraction of a second counts, the time it takes to say an extra word like "please" might be crucial.

(c) If the sentence already has other polite words. Like your example, "Feel free to look around." "Feel free" already makes the command polite. "Please feel free" is probably overkill. One polite word or phrase is normally sufficient. Unless you're desperately begging, like, "Please, if you would, if it isn't too much trouble, would you consider, maybe possibly ..."

(d) If the imperative is something that is for the hearer's own benefit, adding "please" may not be necessary, and indeed may make it sound like you are asking them to do it for your benefit. Like, "Have another piece of cake" versus "Please take another piece of cake." The first would be understood to be giving the person the option. If they don't want any more cake, they can say no. But the second implies that you want them to take the cake, like you are afraid the person who baked the cake will have hurt feelings if too little of it is eaten or some such.

Comment: Great explanations!

Answer (score 0):

*'Please'* is word that is mostly used in polite requests. You can use please almost anywhere. Say, you're angry at someone, even then you could use please:

> - Buzz off, please.
> - Please go kill yourself.
> - Please leave me alone.

So there isn't any hard and fast rule when it comes to the usage of *'please'*. Then there are occasions when the use of *"please"* is necessary, **it's not mandatory**, but it should be used generally. For example:

> - Please remain quiet.
> - Please don't smoke here.
> - Please come here.

These sentences all include a request to the listener to do something. Now, if the listener thinks your request is too harsh, he may not consider listening to you. That's why you add a *"courtesy"* factor to your sentence.

The main purpose of the word *"please"* is to add a respectful and polite note, so as to make the listener feel good. It is always good to be polite to another person, especially a stranger. There are few limits to the use of *"please"*; however, you must be very careful that you don't overuse it and sound too cheesy. Nobody listens to somebody who is way too polite, even in this harsh world. Try to limit the use of *"please"* and use it the right amount of times. You'll get a hang of it once you start using it extensively.

Comment: What about "Feel free to look around" as you often hear in a store?

Comment: "Please feel free to look around" is perfectly acceptable and unquestionably polite.

Comment: As mentioned by user3169 in the comments for your question, *"Feel free to look around"* is not a request, it's a permission. Even if he doesn't _'look around'_, it doesn't matter. On the other hand, if we say _"Do not smoke here"_, we want him to stop smoking, regardless of the reason. So that's a request. So the best way to ask that would be _"Please do not smoke here"_. On a different note, you could add _'please'_ to _'feel free to look around'_. There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Maybe there's nothing wrong with saying "Please feel free to look around".
It seems to me that "Feel free to look around" is more common.

Comment: @ASTPace  I'm asking which is better, using "please" or not, for example in a case like "Feel free to look around". Just knowing "Please feel free to look around" is perfectly acceptable and polite is not enough.

Comment: @MakotoKato, you cannot assume one is better than the other here. Using _'please'_ increases the politeness factor of the sentence. You could either say _"Please feel free to look around"_ or _"Feel free to look around"_. Both these sentences are pretty polite and you could use either of them. **Having said that the sentence is polite enough to start with, you could even omit the _'please'_ without it sounding impolite.**

Comment: @VarunKN - RE: _you could omit the 'please' without it sounding impolite_ - I agree.  RE: _using 'please' increases the politeness factor of the sentence - Er, maybe. Not necessarily. It could make a salesperson sound desperate.

Comment: @J.R, that is true. Although the salesperson may appear desperate to us, he over uses *'please'* to make him sound super polite. It sounds cheesy, to us because we oversee his desperation.

Comment: @VarunKN - True – but that contradicts the premise of your answer: _IMO, you can never be too polite. In fact, you can use ‘please’ anywhere._ If you use the word _too_ often by inserting it unnecessarily, there might be some diminishing returns: it might come off as desperate, mechanical, awkward, unnatural, forced, or insincere.

Comment: All right. I'll make suitable edits. I didn't think of it that way. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @ASTPace Please see my new edit. People use "Feel free to" far more frequently than "Please feel free to".

Comment: In a comment I responded to your comment.  It was not meant to suggest that using "please" always makes sense.  I stand by my comment, which is not meant as an answer to your main question.

Comment: Sometimes it is **not** "good to be polite to someone".  Also, sometimes you need an *immediate* response, and extra "polite" words would slow things down.  For example, if someone seems to be choking, I ask "Are you OK?"  Any audible verbal answer will tell me that they are not choking.

Comment: @Jasper, but that's not the question here. You're barking up the wrong tree. I never said you can use _"please"_ everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different take on this from the other commenters. Putting aside "watch out" and the Steve Job quote for the moment, the other examples you cite, while expressed with the imperative, do not represent a demand, but rather a wish or hope by the speaker, e.g., "(I hope you) have a nice weekend" or "(I would like you to) feel free to look around." Steve Jobs is not issuing a demand, but offering advice:  "(I advise you to) stay hungry."

You can drop the "please" from "Watch out!" because you are being playful (said while smiling), because of urgency (it'll be too late if you take time to say please), or because you are angry or serious (not trying to be polite).